# Проксирование траффика

Tags: веб-программирование, администрирование, proxy

Допустим, есть один сайт и есть мобильное приложение. Мобильное приложение работает через парсинг html страничек. Я хочу поставить между приложением и сайтом прокси-сервер, который будет все запрошенное парсить и отдавать JSON.

**Вопрос:**
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы для админов сайта в статистике отображался ip адрес и прочие данные запросившего, а не ip прокси-сервера? Где тут будут тонкие моменты (на сайте используется csrf и идентификация пользователя происходит через куки)? Может, есть уже подобные сервисы, которые я могу использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете доступ к настройкам сервера, то его можно настроить считать ваш сервер прокси и брать ip адрес запросившего.

Ваш прокси должен посылать заголовок X-Forwarded-For, а на сервере должно быть разрешено его использовать. Например для Apache это делается опцией Proxy.

Comment: К серверу доступа нет. Задумка чтобы удаленный сервер не подозревал что трафик идет с прокси. То есть сделать прокси абсолютно прозрачным, пропускающим через себя все пакеты без изменения. Хочу написать прокси-парсер для одного сервиса.